# Any learning/studying material for C/C++ that use game programming as learning context out there?

Tags: c++, architecture

As most of game programming is done - I read on this very site - in C/C++ I was wondering if there is any learning/studying material for C/C++ that would target specifically game programming.

I am not looking for material about "developing games" or "software architecture for games", but rather for **material that uses "game programming" as the CONTEXT for introducing and illustrating C/C++ features, idioms, programming techniques, etc...**

With a simile: think to the [GOF book on design patterns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_Patterns). There, they used "developing a text-editor" as a context for introducing design patterns, but the book is most definitively not a book about "developing text-editors".

**EDIT:** The book should contain code examples that are not dependant on proprietary technologies (e.g.: it should use OpenGL rather than DirectX, a dialect of C known to gcc rather than needing a specific commercial compiler, etc...)

Thanks in advance for your time and advice!

PS: My background: I am a programmer with a solid experience in OO scripting languages and only some experience in C and Assembler (on AVR microcontrollers), so I am thinking to mid-to-advanced level material, rather than tutorials for beginners, although it might be interesting to take a look to the latter ones if nothing else is available.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's [Beginning C++ Through Game Programming](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1598633600)..I found it to be a good book. All the examples it works on are small, text-based games.

If you're talking more advanced, I haven't seen anything like that.

Comment: Reading Amazon's reviews it looks like I'm looking for something fairly more advanced. Yet, +1 because this is exactly the *kind* of book that I am looking for.

Comment: @mac: Well, which is it?  You want a beginner's book that teaches C++, or something advanced?

Comment: @BlueRaja I'm pretty sure he's looking for the equivalent of an advanced C++ book with a gamedev setting.

Comment: @BlueRaja - Read the question again (last paragraph!) ;)

Answer (score 3):

There's [C++ For Game Programmers](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1584504528) but maybe [Game Coding Complete](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1584506806) will be a better match (although it does not focus on C++ only but there are some good chapters on C++ specific problems).

Comment: On one hand, I recommend Game Coding Complete hugely. Absolutely great book on a number of topics. However, the OP is looking for a book where the focus is C++ with a gamedev context, rather than the other way around which GCC is.

Comment: From what I understand from the Amazon reviews, C++ for game programmers seem to be a good fit (+1). Game coding complete - OTOH - seems a bit off my priorities right now, but I keep on reading (here and elsewhere) that it's a very good book, so maybe not now but in a little while... :)

Answer (score 1):

I really enjoyed this book

[http://www.amazon.co.uk/Beginning-Game-Programming-Jonathan-Harbour/dp/1598632884/ref=sr_1_14?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1309350818&sr=1-14](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1598632884)

this starts with windows programming then direct x in 2d then 3d.

a brilliant book to follow Beginning C++ Through Game Programming

Comment: Thanks for this. I did not specify this in my original question (I am going to do it now!) but a book which is tightly coupled to Windows is a no-go for me, as my development platform is GNU/Linux.

Comment: @mac in that case check out the authors other books the guy programs in a whole bunch of stuff

Answer (score 1):

Here you go: 20 online lessons. It starts from "zero", but you can skip/skim the beginner parts. Also perhaps the school offers more advanced material.

## [Introduction to C++ with Game Development](http://www.devmaster.net/articles/intro-to-c++-with-game-dev/part1.php)

#### Learning C++ in the context of game development

> Welcome to the first article of
> Learning C++ tutorial series, provided
> by the IGAD program of the NHTV
> University! These tutorials are
> designed to take you from zero to
> block 3 entry level of IGAD's program
> in a somewhat smooth fashion. We start
> at the absolute basics: all that you
> need to get started is some decent
> equipment, a fair bit of time, and
> quite a bit of dedication.

...

> A quick blurb about us: IGAD stands
> for "International Game Architecture &
> Design". We are a Dutch accredited
> course for game development, ran
> almost exclusively by teachers with
> game industry experience. We started
> in 2005, and so far, it's awesome.
> About the authors

...

> This tutorial is written by Jacco
> Bikker, Brian Beuken, Nils Deslé, and
> Carlos Bott. Look us up on the
> internet to find out about we did and
> still do related to games development.

Comment: With no discussion of templates, inheritance, virtual functions, or operator overloading, I would be hard-pressed to call that an introduction to C++. It's an introduction to the absolute basics of programming.

Comment: @Joe, @Leftium - I understand the rationale behind the downvote, yet the material (although being for ultimate noobs and so being of little if no use for me) takes precisely the approach that I asked for. +1 for me, as other people looking for something in the line of what I asked could find this answer useful.